# WP-PostRatings save the category id

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP-PostRatings, when anybody vote it saves the post id to database. i want it to save the either category id or name of category.

I have Tried to saved a value to database by the following Code of Wp-postratings plugin

$rate_log = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO {$wpdb->ratings} VALUES (%d, %d, %s, %d, %d, %s, %s, %s, %d )", 0, $catid, $post_title, $ratings_value[$rate-1], current_time('timestamp'), get_ipaddress(), @gethostbyaddr( get_ipaddress() ), $rate_user, $rate_userid ) );

under wp-postratings.php file

and under my theme i have successfully echo a cat id to my file post-single.php by using

now only want to enter this echo value (cat id ) to database when ratting is pressed

Comment: Currently there is no functionality in plugin for taxonomy ratings...
But i have created taxonomy ratings functionality at my end for my project...
So you have to add your code for custom taxonomy ratings...

Comment: i am successful in displaying a category id into post-single.php and now only have to post its value to wp-postratings.php